# How to use JSON returned by jQuery AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following ajax call in my javascript.  This call executes correctly, the appropriate action is taken on the server, and the server returns status 200 and a JSON object containing: a string name `result` containing the value `"OK"` and an array of tuples called `aaData`.  I can see this returned data by spying out the results in Chrome.

My problem is that while `alert("Hello")` executes as expected, and `alert(response)` displays "object" (as I would expect); `alert(response["result"]` displays "undefined".  It appears to me that `response` has already been parsed into a javascript object and I should be able to use it.  Am I wrong?  Is there something else I need to do to the object?  Or am I addressing its elements incorrectly.

```
$.ajax( {type:        "PUT",
     url:         "/fund/${fund.name}/contacts",
     data:        payload,
     contentType: "application/json",
     processData: false,
     cache:       false,
     dataType:    "application/json",
     complete:    function(response) {
            alert("Hello");
            alert(response);
            alert(response["result"]);
                if (response["result"] != "OK")
            {
                alert(response["result"])
            }
            else
            {
                $("#fund-contacts").dataTable( {"aaData": response["aaData"]} )
            }
            $("#fund-contact-entry").dialog( "close" );
            alert("Hello");
              }
    }
);
```

Comment: `dataType` should be `json`, not `application/json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `success` callback instead of `complete`.

From the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> **success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)**
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object
>
> **complete(jqXHR, textStatus)**
>
> A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request

*Edit: Also, what @hobbs says above*

Comment: Thanks Phil and hobbs.  Both changes were necessary (complete doesn't receive the data from the AJAX request).